# Merging 2, 1 row data.tables on column names

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have 2, 1 row data.tables.

```
dt1 <- data.table(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0)
dt2 <- data.table(a = 1, c = 5)
```

My goal is to update `dt1` with the values of `dt2` so that I get:

```
desired_dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 0, c = 5)
```

I tried merging, assuming it'd match on the shared column names, but no luck.

```
dt2[dt1]
```

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt2, dt1) : 
When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' 
argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by 
sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed 
benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

Wouldn't this be considered a natural join?  I'd appreciate any help on what I'm missing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the `intersect`ing column names and do the assignment

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(dt1), names(dt2))
dt1[, (nm1) := dt2]
```

---

Or we can `set` the key

```
setkeyv(dt1, intersect(names(dt1), names(dt2)))
out <- dt1[dt2]
for(j in seq_along(out)) set(out, i = which(is.na(out[[j]])), j=j, value = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That 1st solution works and isn't something I would have considered.  The 2nd solution however, should retain the b = 0 value from dt1, not replace it with NA

Comment: Your first approach works like a charm! Like it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option using `rbindlist` + `fcoalesce`

```
setcolorder(
  rbindlist(
    list(dt2, dt1),
    fill = TRUE
  )[
    ,
    lapply(.SD, function(x) fcoalesce(as.list(x)))
  ], names(dt1)
)[]
```

which gives

```
   a b c
1: 1 0 5
```